# Obtain Kubernetes API key with Java

Tags: java, kubernetes, oauth

I'm using k8s java client and need a way to get OAuth access token for some clusters. Now I can do that only with this bash script:

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/<config-file>

APISERVER=$(kubectl config view --minify | grep server | cut -f 2- -d ":" | tr -d " ")
SECRET_NAME=$(kubectl get secrets | grep ^default | cut -f1 -d ' ')
TOKEN=$(kubectl describe secret $SECRET_NAME | grep -E '^token' | cut -f2 -d':' | tr -d " ")

echo "TOKEN: ${TOKEN}"
```

Is there a way to do that with java code? Don't ask for the whole solution but at least for some direction to look.

Comment: I don't program on Java, but I'm sure you can handle a file there too. Something like defining a `file`, then `file.open`, stream it into your code, parse it and get the information you need. Probably on Java you will find several ways of doing this.

Comment: Your bash scripts gets the “default” service account token secret. If your want to interact to your Kubernetes cluster by using JAVA libraries you can use the java kubernetes-client (https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java). Have you tried to use the client?

Comment: I need to request OAuth token to access the cluster. That couldn't be done by parsing of kubeconfigs.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes is not involved in the OAuth side of things at all. That’s up to your IdP. More normally you would use a ServiceAccount token for automation though.

Answer (score 0):

The Kubernetes config is stored as a YAML file. Use a library to read and parse it, [example](https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml)

In the end you'll get an object with all the keys and values from the config. Just access directly what you need.

Comment: May be the question is not 100% clear. How I understand I need request OAuth token from the kubernates cluster. That's not possible by parsing of kubeconfigs.

Comment: Not sure if you really need to use OAuth. Usually tokens are used when communicating with the API server.